# Strange multisite issue where all sites return same id with get_current_site()

Tags: multisite

I'm trying to add some code based on which multisite is shown. However for both the main site and sub-domains it always shows the ID as 1. I've put

```
$current_site = get_current_site();
var_dump($current_site);
```

in both the header.php and index.php and they both output the same for every sub-domain:

```
object(WP_Network)[275]
  private 'id' => int 1
  public 'domain' => string '...' (length=16)
  public 'path' => string '/' (length=1)
  private 'blog_id' => int 1
  public 'cookie_domain' => string '...' (length=16)
  public 'site_name' => string '...' (length=19)
```

Has anyone else ran into this issue and know of a way to get the correct current id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Multisite was first rolled into core (from a project call "multi-user", which is why you'll sometimes see references to "mu-*"), the terminology was that you'd run a **site** of **blogs**. Now we refer to a **network** of **sites**, but because the functions had all already been named, [`get_current_site()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_site/) gets the current **network**.

You'll need to use [`get_current_blog_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_blog_id/) to get the current **site**'s ID, or [`get_bloginfo()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/) or [`get_blog_details()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_blog_details/) for more detailed data on the current site.

### Reference

- [Note on `get_current_site`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_site/#comment-2415)

Comment: Much appreciated, yeah the legacy naming issues have tripped me up a few times. get_current_site() works exactly as I needed it. Thanks again

Comment: Since 4.6 you can get the current _network_ with `get_network()`, if you want to avoid this ambiguity in your code.